# Use of “by“ in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

Let's say that someone borrow ten dollars from me. Would it be correct if that person say by using the preposition "by" that

> I became indebted by 10$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[It's correct.](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/indebted-to-for-in-by-with/) The $ sign goes just in front of the amount.

> I became indebted by $10.

There is an implied "the amount of" between the by and the $10.

Comment: Correct maybe but not natural at all. "To become indebted" is very stiff and antiquated for everyday language. "I owe you $10."

Comment: I have downvoted the answer as I think it is misleading. I have never come across and can find no reference to the phrase **to become indebted by** any amount.

Comment: @RonaldSole  Look farther.

Comment: @puppetsock I shall gladly reverse my vote and opinion if you can source your answer adequately.

Comment: @RonaldSole Nope. Wouldn't want you to actually have to read the link I provided. You leave that down-vote right where it is.

Comment: @puppetsock The question is whether the construction **indebted by** an amount is idiomatic. Your own source makes it clear that **indebted by** is found in just 1% of examples, only two of which contain amounts (in eastern currencies). There is not a single example I can find using this construction with dollar, pound or euro amounts, the world's major trading currencies. So I continue to believe that people don't speak like that and that your answer is misleading. I would welcome other opinions.